# Excel extract specific number from cell

Tags: excel, format, cell

i have excel cell inputs like this:

```
Line 644: 6
```

or

```
Line 1004:
```

the only thing i need is the number next to the **":"** so in the above cases i need

644 and 1004. all cells are formatted as "general" is there a quick way to remove the other not needed characters and only extract the needed numbers ?

i tried with =LEFT(Q2,4) for the first example above, but this gives me an error "The formula you typed contains an error"

Comment: Do all cells start with "`Line `"?

Comment: Try `=TRIM(MID(Q2,FIND(" ",Q2),FIND(":",Q2)-FIND(" ",Q2)))`

Comment: @cybernetic yes all cells start with "Line"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
=MID(MID(A1,1,FIND(":",A1)-1),FIND(" ",MID(A1,1,FIND(":",A1)-1))+1,9999)
```

[image]

MUCH more reliable would be:

```
Public Function GetNumber(r As Range) As Variant
    Dim arr, L As Long, i As Long, CH As String, temp As String

    GetNumber = ""
    arr = Split(r.Value, ":")
    L = Len(arr(0))
    CH = ""
    temp = ""

    For i = L To 1 Step -1
        CH = Mid(arr(0), i, 1)
        If CH Like "[0-9]" Then
            temp = CH & temp
        Else
            GetNumber = temp
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i

    GetNumber = temp
End Function
```

Because this UDF() does not rely on a single space before the number.

**BY THE WAY:**

if a formula like:

```
 =LEFT(Q2,4)
```

does not work, next try:

```
 =LEFT(Q2;4)
```

instead.

Comment: i will try it with your function because with these formulas i keep getting "The formula you typed contains an error"

Comment: @friggler  see my **By the way**

Comment: thank you so much that ";" did the trick :-) now the formulas work. god i hate excel

Answer (score 0):

Slightly shorter than other formula offers (so far) while also converting result to Numeric format:

```
=1*MID(LEFT(A1,FIND(":",A1)-1),6,LEN(A1))
```

Comment: i keep getting this "The formula you typed contains an error". i tried all suggested formulas. i also tried selecting the entire column and changing the format to "text" or "number" but then nothing happens the formula e.g. "=TRIM(...)" is just inserted as text